MS Visual Studio 2022 'could not load or assembly Microsoft.Data.SQLClient'
I need to create a simple application but having some difficulties.
I'm trying to create a new project Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) in MS Visual Studio 2022.
I get the following error when trying to connect a data source via Data Source Connection Wizard:
Could not load or assembly Microsoft.Data.SQLClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
When I try to create a data source connection to the database using the Data Source Configuration Wizard, and test the connection everything is so far so good.
But once I select the table I want or need, I get the error:
I can see the connection through the Server Explorer, but not via the Data Source tab so I can add to form with controls.  Ive also tried to look for the dependencies via Solution Explorer (Not sure if that's where to find them) but was unable to solve.
Ive searched all over the web for a solution (no pun intended) and have not found a simple or clear fix/Guide.

According to Nuget for version 5.0.0:  This package has been deprecated as it has critical bugs. The latest version is 5.2.0.

You may consider downloading/installing SQL Server Management Studio and using that instead.

That sounds more like a VS issue than a project issue. I'd start by trying a brand new project to see whether the same thing happens. If it does, a repair of VS is probably in order.

Try installing the latest version of Microsoft.Data.SQLClient for your project in the Nuget Package Manager.
